# Does this make my XtraDB Cluster hang?

Tags: mysql, replication, percona, xtradb-cluster, xtradb

After seeing the following in the error log on the second node:

```
121003  7:16:06 [Note] WSREP: Member 0 (joiner) synced with group.
121003  7:16:06 [Note] WSREP: Shifting JOINED -> SYNCED (TO: 0)
121003  7:16:06 [Note] WSREP: Synchronized with group, ready for connections
121003  7:16:06 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
121003  7:17:08 [Note] WSREP: Skipping empty log_xid: COMMIT
121003  7:17:08 [Note] WSREP: ignoring DDL failure: 0 ALTER TABLE bigdata_queue_campaigns DISABLE KEYS
121003  7:17:08 [Note] WSREP: Skipping empty log_xid: COMMIT
121003  7:17:08 [Note] WSREP: ignoring DDL failure: 0 ALTER TABLE bigdata_queue_campaigns ENABLE KEYS

...
```

`121003  7:31:33 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'Table 'reportingdb.norep_zonebannertmp_bk' doesn't exist' on query. Default database: 'reportingdb'. Query: 'TRUNCATE TABLE norep_zonebannertmp_bk', Error_code: 1146`

```
121003  7:31:33 [Warning] WSREP: RBR event 1 Query apply warning: 1, 1141
```

`121003  7:31:33 [Warning] WSREP: Ignoring error for TO isolated action: source: 84dcb35c-0ce4-11e2-0800-4568aec9a7f3 version: 2 local: 0 state: APPLYING flags: 65 conn_id: 1106 trx_id: -1 seqnos (l: 1196, g: 1141, s: 1140, d: 1140, ts: 1349224295344525000)`

I cannot login to the first node `mysql -u root -p` hangs. I don't see any interesting in the error log on this node.

I'm using Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-server-5.5.27-23.6.356.rhel5.

Let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 1):

If the table `reportingdb.norep_zonebannertmp_bk` does not exist on one of the nodes in the Cluster, this could be the source of your problem. Why? `TRUNCATE TABLE` is DDL. That will close the current transaction PXC has during WriteSet Operations. This cannot be rolled back. I would expect a PXC communication problem at `COMMIT` time because [*`TRUNCATE TABLE` causes implicit COMMIT (See my StackOverflow post from May 12, 2011)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5972738/491757). If the table `reportingdb.norep_zonebannertmp_bk` had existed in every node in the Cluster, then the `TRUNCATE TABLE` would execute without an error. You should check for any BugReports about this. You should probably submit this as a question to Percona.

There are two methods you may want to try to clear this up:

## METHOD #1

You could recreate the table on the PXC (Percona XtraDB Cluster) that has the table missing

- Step01) Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE reportingdb.norep_zonebannertmp_bk\G` on Node that still has table
- Step 02) Copy and Paste that Query into `/root/Fix.sql`
- Step 03) Change `CREATE TABLE` to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` in `/root/Fix.sql`
- Step 04) Execute `/root/Fix.sql` on the PXC node that does not have the table

## METHOD #2

You may have to perform a full SST in the event other tables are out of sync. The most aggressive way to do this is the following:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
service mysql stop
rm -f /var/lib/mysql/galera.cache /var/lib/mysql/grastate.dat
service mysql start
```

Since there is no `/var/lib/mysql/galera.cache`, IST cannot be done. SST would be initiated.

Comment: Method #1 cannot be done because I even cannot log in to the node that doesn't have this table. Is there any better way to handle this case instead of doing a SST?

Comment: SST is better option. so that any data inconsistency other than this also will be removed.